# How do I parse this back to a mm/dd/yyyy format?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have some dates in a Google Spreadsheet that I'm bringing in to a script like this:

```
  var JCstartDateFix = Math.floor(Date.parse(JCstartDate) / 86400000) + 25570;
  var todaysDateFix = Math.floor(Date.parse(todaysDate) / 86400000) + 25570;
```

How do I do the opposite of this at the end of the script to change it back into a mm/dd/yyyy formatted date?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Here's the whole script:

```
function projectedDate(JCstartDate, overallPercent, pace, todaysDate, HSstartDate, DaysInHS) {

//converts dates to a number of days
var JCstartDateFix = Math.floor(Date.parse(JCstartDate) / 86400000) + 25570;
var todaysDateFix = Math.floor(Date.parse(todaysDate) / 86400000) + 25570;


//This says that there's no projected date since the student hasn't started high school yet
if(HSstartDate == ""){
  return "HS not started";
}

 //This calculates grad date if the student's been here more than 8 months or if their percent is over 80.
else if(DaysInHS >= 200 || overallPercent >=80){ 
    var percentPerDay = overallPercent/(DaysInHS);
    var daysLeft = (100 - overallPercent) / percentPerDay;

    if((todaysDateFix + daysLeft) > (JCstartDateFix +730)){
      return "You are not on track to complete.";
    }
    else{
      return (todaysDateFix + daysLeft);
    }
  }

 //This calculates grad date if the student's been at JC less than 8 months  
 else{
 if(JCstartDateFix + 600 - pace > JCstartDateFix + 730){
          return "You are not on track to complete.";
       }
      else{
          return (JCstartDateFix+600-pace);
  }

 }
}
```

I work in a school where students start at different times and work at their own pace.  They have a 2 year limit to finish.  So this script estimates their graduation date based on when they started and how fast they're going.  It uses different formulas depending on how long they've been here.  I'm happy with the dates I get on my spreadsheet, but if I format them from the spreadsheet, another script doesn't correctly pick up the text strings and gives a date in 1969 instead.

I think what I need to do is change the lines that return numbers so that those numbers are formatted as dates.  I just don't know how.  Thanks again!

Comment: To make your question more readable, you should use 4 blank characters before the lines of code. I'd fix it myself, but the edit rules say it's too small a change.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the value that you're setting in the spreadsheet is a Date object in apps script, it will appear as a date. The format will be under the control of the spreadsheet, of course, but it defaults to mm/dd/yyyy.

For example, you could just change your existing code to render `Date` objects. Then, when you call `setValue()` you will write a date out to the spreadsheet.

```
var JCstartDateFix = new Date(Math.floor((Date.parse(JCstartDate) / 86400000) + 25570)*86400000); 
var todaysDateFix = new Date(Math.floor((Date.parse(todaysDate) / 86400000) + 25570)*86400000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you get with `Date.parse()` is in milliseconds, you divide it by the number of milliseconds in a day so I guess you obtain the number of days since the JS reference date, rounded to the lowest integer and then add a constant value of 25570.
What is the result supposed to be ?

It seems that it should be a number of day from the ref date but that's quite far in the future !! (about 70 years) Is this right ? could you clarify ?

Anyway, what you should do is to get a value in milliseconds again and use `new Date(value in mSec)` to get a date object. From there `Utilities.formatDate` will allow you to get any display format you want.

ref : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe it would help to post the whole script:

Comment: indeed ;-) or at least explain a bit more ^^

Comment: Sorry, I just realise your comment was addressed to me... in my mind it was sort of answering my info request on you data :-)

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I updated my post with the whole script and tried to give some additional context to what it does.  I'm also trying to use some of the suggestions given above, but I'm a little beyond my meager Javascripting abilities.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I still don't understand what this 25570 is for in your day math...

Comment: Before I put the + 25570 in there, the date I got back had the wrong year.  By trial and error, I found that adding that got the correct year.  If I take it out, the spreadsheet shows the year as 1943 rather than 2013.  I have no idea why though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure out how and why ( but it will be for tomorrow, too tired tonight) (I'm in GMT+1:-)

Comment: The reason for the ~70 year difference is that `Date.parse()` will return the number of milliseconds from 1st Jan 1970 (the JS epoch) where a spreadsheet date is represented as the number of days from 30th Dec 1899.

Comment: Of course Adam has the answer ;-) he has one foot in spreadsheets and the other in Javascript... his head is necessarily somewhere in between ;-D -- thanks Adam